# Abstract Class vs Class

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-class

```
abstract class ClassStupid
{
    public ClassStupid()
    {

    }
}

ClassStupid stupid = new ClassStupid(); //This is not possible. We can not create an Instance of Abstract Class.
```

My question is what is the `MAGIC` in the C# compiler that prevents the program to create an instance of abstract class inspite of having a constructor.

From my Wiki

*In object-oriented programming, a constructor (sometimes shortened to ctor) in a class is a special type of subroutine called at the creation of an object. It **prepares the new object** for use, often accepting parameters which the constructor uses to set any member variables required when the object is first created. It is called a constructor because it constructs the values of data members of the class.*

How is the abstract class constructor different from Normal class Constructor?

Comment: You mean you have never gone to wizard school?

Comment: What makes you think the magic is in the CLR? I get a compile error trying to compile something similar.

Comment: No difference. It just don't allow public access.

Comment: It's not magic... it's the specification of C#, which the compiler of course follows.  Not sure why there is confusion here...

Comment: @JohnSaunders I thought it is in CLR SPEC. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You're wrong. The C# compiler gives me an error: "error CS0144: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface". And -1 for a badly thought-out question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructors of abstract and non-abstract classes are not different; the classes, however, are different, and the compiler knows about that. This is the reason the construction of abstract classes the way you show in the post is prohibited: the compiler simply checks the `IsAbstract` flag, and disallows the construction at compile time.

Moreover, CLR also has a runtime flag indicating that a class is abstract. That is why you wouldn't be able to instantiate an abstract class at runtime through *reflection*.